Does Safe protocol Kit support sponsoring deployment transactions?
From  a previous question in january I know Safe team has been working on this feature, is this available already?

They are enabling gasless transactions by leveraging the ERC-4437 features. You can check how to sponsor the deployment of an ERC-4337 Safe account and its user operation on their documentation.
